# Simulate HTML form in Android

Tags: android, html, forms, http, request

I have a HTML form and I want to simulate a request with all boxes filled out. 
Thanks in advance :)

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <input type="file" name="datei"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password"></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Hochladen" name="upload"> 
</form>
```

This is my Java code by now, but I'm only able to transfer the file, not the "password":

```
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL("example.com/upload.php");

               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true);
               conn.setDoOutput(true);
               conn.setUseCaches(false);
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("datei", fileName);

               DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"datei\"; filename=\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               //...

               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();
```

Comment: Please don't self-vandalize your posts.

Comment: This answer may solve the problem for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34409142/1617737 :-)

Answer (score 1):

When using multipart/form-data you should pass multiple bundles, one for each variables. However this way to push data into your request is unsafe, you should use a MultipartEntity object, take a look at this: [Multipart/form-data construction with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553507/multipart-form-data-construction-with-android)

For multipart/form-data reference see this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Keep in mind that you could also post multiple variables in a single body using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" enctype, which is the default for html forms.